# Firebase: How should I structure my database? Like Offerup and Letgo

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am currently building an iOS app that basically allows users to post items that they want to sell and other users can then search for items to purchase based on location. How should I structure my database?

I currently have the following structure in mind:

```
users {
    userID: {
        profileImage:
        username:
    }
    .
    .
    .
}


posts: {
    userID: {
        postID: {
            description:
            imageUrl:
            creationDate:
            price:
            location:
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Hope what I am asking makes sense. In other words, how would an app like OfferUp or Letgo structure their database? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say - it depends how the rest of your application is going to work, but IMO instead of nesting `postID` under `userID` you would be better to add the `userID` to the post object.

```
posts: {
    postID: {
        description:
        imageUrl:
        creationDate:
        price:
        location:
        userID:
    }
}
```

Reasons;

- Will allow you to run searches across all items, you don't need to search each user - then each item. Deep searching records isn't possible.
- Your database rules can keep `posts` readable by all but then only `editable/writeable` where the `auth.uid` = `userID`.
- Can still each by `userID` by nesting this way.

Comment: Okay. What is the best way to display items based on location? Considering that items can be from anywhere in the US. How do apps like Letgo and Offerup handle it?

Comment: I don't know what Letgo and Offerup are, but you could store a state, zip or city in the `postID` and allow users to search via state and see all items in their state.

Comment: There are also zip or city databases that allow you to find nearby areas and you could search all those nearby areas for the item.

Comment: As I asked Alexandre above, how would I efficiently search for posts within a certain zip code if I have 100,000+ posts? Is this something that GeoFire is used for?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I would change is that if you want to be able to show a list of the different items on sale, you should extract the information needed for the list to another root-level collection. You should put less details in that section, as Google says that it will allow the data to be downloaded faster, while using less data. (source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)

So, something like this:

```
{
    users: {
        userID: {
            profileImage:
            username:
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }


    posts: {
        zipCode: {
            postID: {
                userID: 
                description:
                imageUrl:
                creationDate:
                price:
                location:
            }
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }

    listOfPosts: {
        zipCode: {
            postID: { //Only put essential information for your list of posts here
                imageURL:
                price:
                location:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Okay makes sense. What about locations? Would I have another root level collection for locations??

Comment: No. If you want to display your items based on their location, simply add the location data to each post in listOfPosts (as I just did). The idea of having listOfPosts is to have a more light JSON to download, and make your app faster. For example, there is no need to download your description while displaying the list of items (their description will only be needed when the user selects one of the item). It might be more clear in the link that I posted above.

Comment: I understand having a more light weight JSON to download but if I have 100,000+ posts and I want to search for posts within a particular zip-code, how would I do that? Isn't traversing all records going to be a slow operation?

Comment: If you wish your users to search by zip code, you can group the posts by Zip code, and then have their list of IDs. You won't have a huge number of posts by zip code.